Applescript closing wrong app after I associated the name with wrong process
I copied this script, and it works great:
set myDoNotQuitList to {"Keyboard Maestro", "Chrome", "Script Editor", "Finder"}

tell application "System Events"
    set quit delay to 0
    set appList to name of processes whose background only is false
end tell

repeat with i in appList
    if i is in myDoNotQuitList then set contents of i to 0
end repeat

set appList to text of appList

repeat with i in appList
    tell application i to quit
end repeat

However, when I ran it the first time, I got a dialog box when trying to close Microsoft Teams, asking me which running app/process was associated with "Microsoft Teams". I chose the wrong process.
My Question is: how do I reset this association, so I can associate the application name in my script with the correct process? I'm assuming it's in a plist somewhere?

What is set contents supposed to be doing?

If all you're trying to do is quit any running applications except for those listed in myDoNotQuitList you can simply do:
set myDoNotQuitList to {"Keyboard Maestro", "Chrome", "Script Editor", "Finder", "Microsoft Teams"}

tell application "System Events"
    set quit delay to 0
    set appList to name of processes whose background only is false
end tell

repeat with i in appList
    if i is not in myDoNotQuitList then
        try
            tell application i to quit
        on error errMsg
            display alert "Error quitting application: " & i & ". " & errMsg
        end try
    end if
end repeat

I'm assuming your issue with the association arose due to the prior script using set contents of i to 0 and the redundancy of set appList to text of appList. Did you check if Microsoft Teams process/application was still actually running when the prompt appeared? I'd be leaning towards ambiguity in the list declaration that was causing apple to look for a process it had already closed out.
Update the script, re-open the Teams app, and run it again. The selected association may be a temporary one-time PID selection of running processes.
